# How/where to embed/add the API Key for Google Sheets in Android Studio

Tags: android, api-key, google-sheets-api, androidhttpclient

After wading through 100+ SO articles, I am acutely aware of how swampy the topic of Google APIs and credentials is, so I'll try to keep this one narrow and focused.

I want to use a Google Spreadsheet to simply read and write pairs of strings for a flashcard app, nothing fancy. For now, I'm willing to use a **public** spreadsheet to avoid the depression-inducing OAuth2.0 issues.

**[Q1]** If I use a public google sheet, I **only** need an API Key and don't need to monkey around with Client IDs and tokens etc. , it should be very straightforward, right ?

I don't want to post my frankenstein code since it contains a mish-mash of snippets I copied from Google API pages and SO. Just want to clear the smoke and get an idea if I'm on the right path.

**[Q2]** I was tinkering around with 'GoogleAccountCredential' and 'com.google.api.services.sheets', is this all OAuth related and should I throw it out ?

**[Q3]** How/Where in my code would I 'bring in' the API Key ? I saw some postings where they point to the manifest, so I added this:

```html
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.sheets.v4.API_KEY"
        android:value="...my API KEY ..."/>
```

or should I simply skip all the 'sheets' package related 'get/update' commands and try it via straightforward HTTP commands (GET/POST/PUT) and embed the API key via '?key=' in the URL?

Is there some simple code snippet to show how to access Google sheets with **only an API key** ?!?

Comment: You may follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android). I don't think that you need the API Key. Just make sure that the field `Package name` is matched with your `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. Yes,
 [`GoogleAccountCredential`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/gms/auth/GoogleAccountCredential) is used to manage authorization and account selection for Google accounts.

Comment: yes, have the package matching in my manifest and devcon.   Pretty sure the tutorial relies on OAuth since they use GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2. My point was that all this isnt' required for **public** spreadsheets. Were you able to  use the snippet succesfully ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call setKey("your_key_here") when execute sheet service

reference here :
[Android Google Sheets API V4 - Update public sheet without OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448553/android-google-sheets-api-v4-update-public-sheet-without-oauth)